# Kafka and Golang with SSL

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I am trying to connect to a topic that requires SSL. Can anyone suggest an approach to achieve this?

I have a ca.crt, ca.p12 and password provided by the kafka cluster administrator.
I can connect just fine using a test utility that leverages the keytool/keystore, but these don't work for Go.

The code to connect to the cluster is as follows:

```
func (p *KafkaPublisher) Initialise() {
    configFile := "./config/kafka.properties"
    fmt.Printf("Reading config file from: %s\n", configFile)
    conf := ReadConfig(configFile)

    var err error
    kafkaProducer, err = kafka.NewProducer(&conf)

    // rest of code commented out.
}
```

And this works just fine for SASL using the following config file:

```
bootstrap.servers=markets-cb--vog--pu-taejvaba.bf2.kafka.rhcloud.com:443
security.protocol=SASL_SSL
sasl.mechanisms=PLAIN
# Service account user name
sasl.username=700e9c83-b4be-4f23-8697-b6cfa5921354
sasl.password=ab955a0d-e78d-4d96-bd8e-35de3b6b83e5

# Best practice for Kafka producer to prevent data loss
acks=all
```

I reviewed the following documentation to try and find the right properties:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/librdkafka/html/md_CONFIGURATION.html#autotoc_md91
and have been unsuccessful

```
bootstrap.servers=my-cluster-kafka-listener1-bootstrap-climate.violet-cluster-new-2761a99850dd8c23002367ac6ce7f9ad-0000.au-syd.containers.appdomain.cloud:443

security.protocol=SSL
ssl.key.password=ebuSuzkDbfFK
ssl.certificate.location="ca.pem"

# Best practice for Kafka producer to prevent data loss
acks=all
```

I have also tried putting the pem file inline as a single quote-delimited line using the property `ssl.certificate.pem`. This produced the the most encouraging result with an error:

```
Failed to create producer: ssl.certificate.pem failed: not in PEM format?: error:0909006C:PEM routines:get_name:no start line: Expecting: CERTIF
```

But it is a PEM file format...

Here is the certificate (Don't worry, there is no security risk with me pasting this in here as the cert is now removed from the server and I changed the url and password above.)

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```